# how to add border to a range of cell using AppleScript

Tags: excel, applescript, excel-2010, excel-2016

I want to add thin border around a range of cell (cell input varies from file to file).

I need someone to help me on this. Finding it more difficult to automate excel with AppleScript.

This is my code

```
set theWorkbookFile to choose file with prompt "Please select an Excel workbook file:"
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    open theWorkbookFile
    set theWorkbook to active workbook
    tell active sheet
        tell used range
            set RowCount to count of rows
            --display dialog RowCount
            set columnCount to count of columns
            --display dialog columnCount
            
            
            repeat with theRowValue from 1 to RowCount
                repeat with theColumValue from 1 to columnCount
                    set theCell to "A" & theColumValue & ":K" & theRowValue
                    --set myRanger to theCell
                    select range theCell
                    --set mySel to selection
                    --set myRange to first item of (get areas of mySel)
                    set myBorders to {border top, border bottom, border left, border right}
                    repeat with i from 1 to 4
                        set theBorder to get border theCell which border (item i of myBorders)
                        --set weight of theBorder to border weight thin
                    end repeat
                end repeat
            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Thanks
Ashwin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set theWorkbookFile to choose file with prompt "Please select an Excel workbook file:"

tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    open theWorkbookFile
    set myBorders to {border top, border bottom, border left, border right}
    tell active workbook to tell active sheet
        
        tell used range to set {rowsCount, columnsCount} to {count of rows, count of columns}
        
        repeat with rowValue from 1 to rowsCount
            repeat with columnValue from 1 to columnsCount
                set theCell to cell ("A" & columnValue & ":K" & rowValue)
                repeat with i from 1 to 4
                    set theBorder to get border theCell which border (item i of myBorders)
                    set weight of theBorder to border weight thin
                end repeat
            end repeat
        end repeat
        
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Robert Kniazidis thanks for the script and it worked perfectly, i made just one modification to my need I just removed columnValue for "A" and made it static as "A1".

Comment: Is there any reference site that I can look forward on learning more on Excel using Applescript.

Thanks

Comment: Exists many guides. Google **microsoft excel applescript guide**